# Laravel 7.14 bulk update form button not workin

Tags: php, html, mysql, laravel, forms

I made a bulk update function in controller where I'm saving single value in multiple rows. For example user input is price = 30. Same 30 will go on the rows where id is equal to [1,2,3,4,5,].

In my update form I have a input field price, if I add `value="{{ $cart->price }}` and send update request with new value like 85. It takes the previous value which is 30.

If I remove the `value="{{ $cart->price }}` from input for submit button becomes disable. I have tried changing  tag to  as well.  Please help figure out what I am doing wrong.

Here's my input code:

```
<div class="form-group">
<input type="text" name="price" value="" class="form-control" required>
</div>
```

Here's my controller:

```
    public function bulkupdate(Request $request)
{
    // dd($request);

    $this->validate($request, [
        'id' => 'required',
        'currency_id' => 'required',
        'price' => 'required',
        'type_id' => 'required',
        'country' => '',
        'port' => '',
    ]);

    $ids = [$request->input('id')];
    $currency_id = $request->input('currency_id');
    $price = $request->input('price');
    $type_id = $request->input('type_id');
    $country = $request->input('country');
    $port = $request->input('port');
    $status = $request->input('status');

    // dd($price);

    foreach($ids[0] as $id) 
    {

        $cart = Cart::where('id', $id)->update([
            
            'status' => $status,
            'currency_id' => $currency_id,
            'price' => $price,
            'type_id' => $type_id,
            'country' => $country,
            'port' => $port,
        ]);

    }

    return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Cart items updates');
}
```

Comment: Can you post the complete form (at least the relevant parts), especially the submit button in question? "_submit button becomes disable_" You mean it gets the `disabled` attribute? Any Javascript involved?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use foreach loop, you can do this by whereIn :

you are sure that all ids are on $ids zero index?
if isn't you can direct give $ids otherwise $ids[0] or $ids is an array so you directly pass $ids in whereIn clause

```
   Cart::whereIn('id', $ids)->update([
        
        'status' => $status,
        'currency_id' => $currency_id,
        'price' => $price,
        'type_id' => $type_id,
        'country' => $country,
        'port' => $port,
    ]);
```

Answer (score -1):

first of all you need to get the record and then `UPDATE` it.

in your code just change this:

```
foreach($ids[0] as $id) 
{
    $cart = Cart::where('id', $id)->first()->update([ 
        'status' => $status,
        .
        .
        .
    ]);
}
```

Comment: @NargeshRana you mean your code can not reach to `Controller` ???

Comment: I mean when I click submit button, nothing happens. Somehow submit button is disabled.

Comment: update your question and add your blade `<form>` tag.